# A program that can run the java classes you made

Tags: java, eclipse

In java programming, how to create a program that let the user input a number then that program runs the program class that you created in the eclipse? for example, I created 10 programs in eclipse, I want to run one at a time without going through each classes, I just need to input number 1 and the first program I made runs. I don't what's it called since I'm really new with Java programming. Please help, thanks.

Comment: what exactly you want? Are you looking for switch case? where you input value to execute particular case..

Comment: I want to have a user input a number then that number is connected to one of the programs I made, like options on what program to run, when the user enters that number, that program associated with that number will run, and at the end, the program will ask the user if the user wants to continue using the program or not, if No the program will bring the user to the main input box and lets the user select other number(associated with one of the programs) he desires.

Comment: It will be better you try some thing on your own.. and put that code here so other can understand and help you to achieve what you want to implement..

Answer (score 0):

Write a single program to launch the others, e.g.

```
public class Multiplexer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    switch (i) {
       case 1: Program1.main(args); break;
       case 2: Program2.main(args); break;
       case 3: Program3.main(args); break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this idea.. What do I put in program1, the name of the program I want to run? =) Thanks..

Comment: I also want to apply scanner on it, like options on what program to run through numbers, and at the end if the user wants to continue using the program or not, if no the program will bring the user to the main input box and selecting other number/program he desires.

Comment: The example shows that from any main program you can invoke the other main methods directly, providing any command line arguments you want. The rest is for you to write.